# A column name can't be found?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do a group by but says:
This is a more detailed question that existed with no answer.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Dataset.csv",encoding = 'UTF-8')
DT #until this all is fine
DT[, sum(as.numeric(Ποσότητα), na.rm=TRUE), by=.(user)]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , sum(as.numeric(Ποσότητα), na.rm = TRUE),
>   :    object 'Ποσότητα' not found
>   >

Useful info:

```
colnames(DT)

"Ημερομηνία" "Χρήστης"  "Ποσότητα" 

DT
     Ημερομηνία Χρήστης   Ποσότητα
  1: 2018-09-03 user_01        -
  2: 2018-09-03 user_01        -
  3: 2018-09-03 user_02        -
  4: 2018-09-03 user_03        -
  5: 2018-09-03 user_04      222
 ---                            
154: 2018-09-10 user_21        1
155: 2018-09-10 user_22     4000
156: 2018-09-10 user_23        3
```

Apparently the name is correct but it doesn't work. I tried it with another dataset with english words and it worked. Maybe it's the dash (-) in that column that causes problem?

If I do this:

```
x=read.table('Dataset_b.csv',
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE,encoding = 'UTF-8',sep =',',header = TRUE)
dt = data.table(x)
dt[, sum(as.numeric(Ποσότητα), na.rm=TRUE), by=.(Χρήστης)]
```

it works normal. But with `fread` doesn't.

What should be done?

Comment: One very inefficient option: `DT[, sum(get("Ποσότητα"))]`

Comment: @Frank it says `Error in sum(get("Ποσότητα")) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`.Also tried : `DT[, sum(get(as.numeric(("Ποσότητα")))]` but said: `Error: unexpected ']' in "DT[, sum(get(as.numeric(("Ποσότητα")))]"`

Answer (score 0):

Dash symbol is a character and you cannot sum them together. You can try add na.strings = “-“ in fread(). Or replace dash with proper NA.

```
   DT[Ποσότητα==“-“, Ποσότητα:=NA]
```